# Grab groups of matches based on strings that start a line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a regex that will capture groups of lines up to and including lines from ^INS through ^DMG. I am able to exclude INS*Y*G8 through DMG. However, I keep getting catastrophic backtracking.

```
INS*Y*G8*030**A***AC~
REF*0F*XXXXXXXX~
NM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*TWDD****34*XXXXXXXXX~
N3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~
N4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~
DMG*D8*19700101*M~
**INS*Y*01*030**A***AC~**
REF*0F*XXXXXXXXX~
NM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*RRWTW****34*XXXXXXXXX~
PER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXX*AP*XXXXXXXXX~
N3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~
N4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~
**DMG*D8*20000101*F~**
**INS*Y*19*030**A***AC~**
REF*0F*XXXXXXXXX~
NM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*GGDFS****34*XXXXXXXXX~
PER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXX*AP*XXXXXXXXX~
N3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~
N4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~
**DMG*D8*20000101*F~**
AMT*D2*100~
AMT*FK*100~
AMT*R*50~
AMT*C1*30~
AMT*P3*31~
AMT*B9*32~
NM1*31*1~
N3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~
N4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~
```

In general, I need a regex that can capture groups of lines given a string that starts a line, up to and including the line that ends the capture group based on another given start of a line.

I have tried this `(INS\*Y\*[^G8]+.*)(.*?)(?=DMG)` and other variations unsuccessfully. What I am expecting is...

Group 1 should be:

```
**INS*Y*01*030**A***AC~**
REF*0F*XXXXXXXXX~
NM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*RRWTW****34*XXXXXXXXX~
PER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXX*AP*XXXXXXXXX~
N3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~
N4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~
**DMG*D8*20000101*F~**
```

Group 2 should be:

```
**INS*Y*19*030**A***AC~**
REF*0F*XXXXXXXXX~
NM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*GGDFS****34*XXXXXXXXX~
PER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXX*AP*XXXXXXXXX~
N3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~
N4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~
**DMG*D8*20000101*F~**
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following regex

```
(?:^|\n)(INS\*(?!Y\*G8)(?:.*\n)+?DMG\S+)
```

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xTlX0i/1) for used Regex.

Here is the Complete python3 code written and tested in Python3 using `re.findall` module of it.

```
re.findall(r"(?m)(?:^|\n)(INS\*(?!Y\*G8)(?:.*\n)+?DMG\S+)",var)
```

Output will be as follows with your shown samples:

`['INS*Y*01*030**A***AC~**\nREF*0F*XXXXXXXXX~\nNM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*RRWTW****34*XXXXXXXXX~\nPER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXX*AP*XXXXXXXXX~\nN3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~\nN4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~\nDMG*D8*20000101*F~**', 'INS*Y*19*030**A***AC~**\nREF*0F*XXXXXXXXX~\nNM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*GGDFS****34*XXXXXXXXX~\nPER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXX*AP*XXXXXXXXX~\nN3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~\nN4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~\nDMG*D8*20000101*F~**']`

***Explanation of Used regex:***

```
(?:^|\n)     ##In a non-capturing group match starting of value OR new line.
(            ##Starting a capturing group from here.
  INS\*      ##Matching INS followed by literal * here.
  (?!Y\*G8)  ##Using negative look ahead to make sure Y*G8 is not present.
  (?:.*\n)+? ##In a non-capturing group matching till new line greedy match with 1 or more matches.
  DMG\S+     ##Matching DMG followed by continuous non-spaces.
)            ##Closing capturing group here.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this thorough explanation! This works and I was also able to capture different line groups based on start of lines. Thank you

Comment: @raveinderSingh13, you edited the OP's data set to remove double asterisks, then did not return the result set he asked for (still missing double asterisks).  OP seems to be OK with that, but this did not exactly solve the stated question as it was asked.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer, well I thought OP is simply trying to highlight data which is needed. Even OP replied in comments that this worked. In case OP comes back I will edit it. In my SO journey have seen people doing it  cheers

Comment: @raveinderSingh13, actually it was my error in the question. Those were code block bold indicators that I forgot to remove. The lines will never start with a double asterisk. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

If the leading `**` in the example for `**INS` text are markers for bold text in the question, then you could write the pattern as:

```
^INS\*(?!Y\*G8).*(?:\n(?!INS\*|DMG\*).*)*\nDMG\*.*
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZOU3t/1)

---

You could use a single match starting with `**INS` and asserting that it is not followed by `Y*G8`

Then match all following lines that do not start with either `**INS` or `**DMG`

```
^\*\*INS(?!Y\*G8).*(?:\n(?!\*\*(?:INS|DMG)).*)*\n\*\*DMG.*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\*\*INS(?!Y\*G8)` Match `**INS` and assert that it is not directly followed by `Y*G8`
- `.*` Match the whole line
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\*\*(?:INS|DMG))` Negative lookahead, assert not `**INS` or `**DMG` directly to the right
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it to match all lines
- `\n\*\*DMG.*` Match a newline, then `**DMG` and the rest of th eline

[Regex demo101](https://regex101.com/r/MwsR4Z/1).

Example code

```
import re

pattern = r"^\*\*INS(?!Y\*G8).*(?:\n(?!\*\*(?:INS|DMG)).*)*\n\*\*DMG.*"

s = ("INS*Y*G8*030**A***AC~\n"
    "REF*0F*XXXXXXXX~\n"
    "NM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*TWDD****34*XXXXXXXXX~\n"
    "N3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~\n"
    "N4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~\n"
    "DMG*D8*19700101*M~\n"
    "**INS*Y*01*030**A***AC~**\n"
    "REF*0F*XXXXXXXXX~\n"
    "NM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*RRWTW****34*XXXXXXXXX~\n"
    "PER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXX*AP*XXXXXXXXX~\n"
    "N3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~\n"
    "N4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~\n"
    "**DMG*D8*20000101*F~**\n"
    "**INS*Y*19*030**A***AC~**\n"
    "REF*0F*XXXXXXXXX~\n"
    "NM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*GGDFS****34*XXXXXXXXX~\n"
    "PER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXX*AP*XXXXXXXXX~\n"
    "N3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~\n"
    "N4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~\n"
    "**DMG*D8*20000101*F~**\n"
    "AMT*D2*100~\n"
    "AMT*FK*100~\n"
    "AMT*R*50~\n"
    "AMT*C1*30~\n"
    "AMT*P3*31~\n"
    "AMT*B9*32~\n"
    "NM1*31*1~\n"
    "N3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~\n"
    "N4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~")

print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M))
```

Output

```
[
'**INS*Y*01*030**A***AC~**\nREF*0F*XXXXXXXXX~\nNM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*RRWTW****34*XXXXXXXXX~\nPER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXX*AP*XXXXXXXXX~\nN3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~\nN4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~\n**DMG*D8*20000101*F~**',
'**INS*Y*19*030**A***AC~**\nREF*0F*XXXXXXXXX~\nNM1*IL*1*JWHWWWW*GGDFS****34*XXXXXXXXX~\nPER*IP**TE*XXXXXXXXX*AP*XXXXXXXXX~\nN3*45874 WHYYWYW WTWYXW~\nN4*DYXWHXVYW*NY*88980~\n**DMG*D8*20000101*F~**'
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You were a little vague on just what your desired stop & start patterns should be, so I assumed a start pattern of <*begin line*> **INS and an end pattern of <*begin line*> **DMG.  If that's not exactly correct you can adjust the regex.

The key to *this* solution, is to set the right set of flags to scan multiple lines correctly.   They are:

- "g" - global - continue to scan for all matches, not just the first
- "s" - single line - `.`matches newline, so multiple lines can be matched with `.+`
- "m" - mult-line - `^` & `$` match <*newline*> as well as begin & end of string.
- "i" - ignore case - May not be necessary, but it can make the patterns shorter.

So, this solution is

```
r"^\*\*INS.*?^\*\*DMG.*?$"gmsi
```

...pretty simple.  Find a ****INS** at the beginning of a line, continue to scan any character across multiple lines until you see a ****DMG** at the beginning of a line, then scan everything up to the next line end.

Here's s a screenprint in Regex101:
[image]

Comment: It think you can make it slightly more efficient for the last line using `^\*\*INS.*?^\*\*DMG[^\n]*$`